# Using multiple excel workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a workbookA which as a formula. The formula uses the values entered in that workbook to compute the result.
For simplicity, say WorkbookA has the following formula in cell C1, =A1+B1.
C1 adds values of A1 and B1.

I have other multiple workbooks that want to use formula in WorkbookA.
These multiple workbooks each have values that have to be passed on to the formula in WorkbookA and want the result back.
Say WorkbookB has 2 values in cell K1, K2. These needs to be passed on the formula in WorkbookA and i want to store the result in K3.

Can someone tell what kind of formula should i write in WorkbookB to achieve this?
If its not possible to simple formula can you please suggest other approaches.

Thanks

Comment: I am assuming the formula is a lot more complicated and A1+B1 and the cell references are always going to be relative to the location of the formula (that is the cell that is immediately to the left plus the cell that is immediately to the left of that one)

Comment: Yes the formula is more complicated than A1+B1. That was just a example.

Comment: You can have different workbooks reference one another.  I would open the two workbooks at the same time and make the formulas like you normally would.  They will refresh and update.  If you need something to do at specific times only, then you might want a macro or VBA code to attach to a button and run selectively.  If the ranges are always the same, I'd go with the formula, if the ranges have to change, some logic and a vb solution is probably best.  It really depends on the specifics of locations and complexity, which isn't provided in the question, so it's hard to advise you.

Comment: WorkbookA takes in 2 values at cells A1 and A2. Apart from these 2 inputs, it uses other data that is available in workbookA to compute the result. The result is available in cell A10 of workbookA. In WorkbookB, I need to use the values in cell A1 and A2, pass these as inputs to WorkbookA. The result from WorkbookA (cell A10 of workbookA) has to be stored in cell A3 of WorkbookB. Similarly i need to use cells B1, B2 in WorkbookB pass these inputs to WorkbookA, get result and store result in B3 in workbookB.

Answer (score 0):

You can do opposite of that. Instead of having answer in sheet B, you can have it in sheet A. To do this, simply write a formula in sheet A and select fields from sheet B.

In short, you can have formula and answer in single sheet but can take input values from different sheets.